# SMS-шлюз Kannel. Throttling error

Tags: sms, очередь, шлюз, smpp

Приветствую!
Требуется специфическое поведение Kannel после получения ошибки throttling:

1. На 60 секунд прекратить отправку любых сообщений.

Данную особенность удалось реализовать с помощью правки исходного файла smsc_smpp.c:
`#define SMPP_THROTTLING_SLEEP_TIME  60`

2. После таймаута посылать не следующее сообщение из очереди, а то сообщение, на которое была получена ошибка.

То есть, если посылать сообщения "1","2","3","4","5", и на сообщение "3" получить throttling error, то Kannel после таймаута пошлёт сообщение "4", потом "5", а только потом "3".

Надо, чтобы после получения throttling error Kannel посылал "3", потом "4", потом "5". Таким образом, чтобы сообщение "3" вставало в начало очереди, а не в конец.

При поиске в Гугле было найдено множество похожих проблем, но нет ни одного работающего решения. Например:

- [Kannel queue type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461349/kannel-queue-type)
- [Handling throttling and message queue full errors](http://kannel.6189.n7.nabble.com/Handling-throttling-and-message-queue-full-errors-td29755.html)
- [How to handle throttling and message queue full errors](http://www.kannel.org/pipermail/users/2014-March/020787.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в моём ответе от 11.11.2016 было рабочим до тех пор, пока не появлялось сообщение с ошибкой Message Queue Full.
По требованием от SMS-центра при получении ошибки MQF должно посылаться следующее сообщение.

Итого, **требования**:

- Throttling Error - таймаут 60 секунд, перепосылаем сообщение с ошибкой
- Message Queue Full - нет таймаута, перепосылаем следующее сообщение из очереди. Сообщение с ошибкой помещаем в конец очереди

**Решение**:

1. Как и написал в вопросе, длительность таймаута регулируется с помощью `SMPP_THROTTLING_SLEEP_TIME` в `smsc_smpp.c`
2. В файле `sms.c` в функции `sms_priority_compare` меняем упорядочивание по времени. Также добавляем упорядочивание по id для составных сообщений:

   ```
   if (msg1->sms.time > msg2->sms.time)
           ret = 1;
   else if (msg1->sms.time < msg2->sms.time)
           ret = -1;
   ```

   меняем на

   ```
   if (msg1->sms.time > msg2->sms.time)
       ret = -1;
   else if (msg1->sms.time < msg2->sms.time)
       ret = 1;
   else {
       if (msg1->sms.id > msg2->sms.id)
           ret = -1;
       else if (msg1->sms.id < msg2->sms.id)
           ret = 1;
       else
           ret = 0;           
   }
   ```
3. По умолчанию при любых ошибках Kannel помещает сообщение в конец очереди. Чтобы отдельно отслеживать TE, в файле `smsc/smsc_smpp.c` меняем функцию `smpp_status_to_smscconn_failure_reason`:

   ```
   static long smpp_status_to_smscconn_failure_reason(long status)
   {
       switch(status) {
           case SMPP_ESME_RMSGQFUL:
           case SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED:
           case SMPP_ESME_RX_T_APPN:
           case SMPP_ESME_RSYSERR:
               return SMSCCONN_FAILED_TEMPORARILY;
               break;

           default:
               return SMSCCONN_FAILED_REJECTED;
       }
   }
   ```

   на

   ```
   static long smpp_status_to_smscconn_failure_reason(long status)
   {
       switch(status) {
           case SMPP_ESME_RMSGQFUL:
           case SMPP_ESME_RX_T_APPN:
           case SMPP_ESME_RSYSERR:
               return SMSCCONN_FAILED_TEMPORARILY;
               break;

           case SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED:
               return SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED;
               break;

           default:
               return SMSCCONN_FAILED_REJECTED;
       }
   }
   ```
4. При получении MQF меняем время сообщения. В противном случае, при получении TE сообщения, которые получили MQF и переместились в конец очереди, будут перемещены в начало очереди. В файле `smsc/smsc_smpp.c` в функции `handle_pdu` в блоке `case submit_sm_resp:` меняем:

   ```
   if (pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status == SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED)
           time(&(smpp->throttling_err_time));
   else
           smpp->throttling_err_time = 0;    

   bb_smscconn_send_failed(smpp->conn, msg, reason, octstr_format("0x%08lx/%s", pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status,
                                       smpp_error_to_string(pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status)));
   ```

   на

   ```
   if (pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status == SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED)
           time(&(smpp->throttling_err_time));
   else
           smpp->throttling_err_time = 0;    

   if (pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status == SMPP_ESME_RMSGQFUL)
           time(&(msg->sms.time));    

   bb_smscconn_send_failed(smpp->conn, msg, reason, octstr_format("0x%08lx/%s", pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status,
                                       smpp_error_to_string(pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status)));
   ```
5. При получении ошибки TE помещаем сообщение в начало очереди. Для этого в файле `bb_smscconn.c` в функции `bb_smscconn_send_failed` меняем:

   ```
   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_TEMPORARILY:     
          ...
          gwlist_produce(outgoing_sms, sms);
          break;

   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_SHUTDOWN:
          gwlist_produce(outgoing_sms, sms);
          break;
   ```

   на

   ```
   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_TEMPORARILY:     
          ...
          gwlist_produce(outgoing_sms, sms);
          break;

   case SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED:   
          gwlist_insert(outgoing_sms, 0, sms);
          break;

   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_SHUTDOWN:
          gwlist_produce(outgoing_sms, sms);
          break;
   ```
6. Аналогично необходимо изменить функцию `handle_split`:

   ```
   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_TEMPORARILY:     
          ...
          gwlist_produce(outgoing_sms, msg);
          break;

   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_DISCARDED:
   ```

   на

   ```
   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_TEMPORARILY:     
          ...
          gwlist_produce(outgoing_sms, msg);
          break;

   case SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED:   
          gwlist_insert(outgoing_sms, 0, msg);
          break;

   case SMSCCONN_FAILED_DISCARDED:
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была решена следующим образом:

```
I did the following patch to smsc/smsc_smpp.c in "case submit_sm_resp:"
section from line 1609:
change
***
if (pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status == SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED)
    time(&(smpp->throttling_err_time));
else
    smpp->throttling_err_time = 0;

bb_smscconn_send_failed(smpp->conn, msg, reason, octstr_format("0x%08lx/%s",
pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status,

 smpp_error_to_string(pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status)));
***
to
***
if (pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status == SMPP_ESME_RTHROTTLED) {
    time(&(smpp->throttling_err_time));
    /* Put the message back into the SMPP queue */
    gw_prioqueue_produce(smpp->msgs_to_send, msg);
} else {
    smpp->throttling_err_time = 0;
    bb_smscconn_send_failed(smpp->conn, msg, reason,
octstr_format("0x%08lx/%s", pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status,
        smpp_error_to_string(pdu->u.submit_sm_resp.command_status)));
}
***

and in sms.c I have changed the function sms_priority_compare() to reverse
time sorting order (for some reason it was LIFO):
if (msg1->sms.time > msg2->sms.time)
    ret = -1;
else if (msg1->sms.time < msg2->sms.time)
    ret = 1;
-------------- next part --------------
```

[SMPP Throttling error processing](http://www.kannel.org/pipermail/devel/2010-February/003341.html)

Но данное изменение не влияет на порядок отправки частей составного сообщения. Чтобы это исправить, необходимо в файле `sms.c` в `sms_priority_compare` добавить сравнение по `sms.id`. При делении сообщения на части в `sms_split` этот ID формируется с помощью `uuid_generate(part->sms.id)`. Итоговая функция `sms_priority_compare` выглядит так:

```
int sms_priority_compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int ret;
    Msg *msg1 = (Msg*)a, *msg2 = (Msg*)b;
    gw_assert(msg_type(msg1) == sms);
    gw_assert(msg_type(msg2) == sms);

    if (msg1->sms.priority > msg2->sms.priority)
        ret = 1;
    else if (msg1->sms.priority < msg2->sms.priority)
        ret = -1;
    else {
        if (msg1->sms.time > msg2->sms.time)
            ret = -1;
        else if (msg1->sms.time < msg2->sms.time)
            ret = 1;
        else {
            if (msg1->sms.id > msg2->sms.id)
                ret = -1;
            else if (msg1->sms.id < msg2->sms.id)
                ret = 1;
            else
                ret = 0;           
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```